# How to set props to state in component in my case?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-props

I am learning React and I am creating an application for myself to keep track of my study. Everything works fine.

In my application I have a class based component in which I have to pass props to state. However, I have learned that I should never pass props to state in a class based component because I could potentially change state somewhere. But I do not know how to make my code work without passing props to state like I am doing. I am self studying so I do not have an instructor to ask, therefore StackOverflow is my best tutor. Thank you in advance for your help.

This is my code.I changed it accordingly to an answer below and it works fine now but is there anything I should change or avoid in my code?

```
import React from 'react';
import SubjectFrom from './SubjectForm';
import {startSubject} from '../actions/subjectAction';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class BeginSubject extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            timeRun:0,
            onFinish:'',
            buttonChange:'start',
            timer:null
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({timeRun:this.props.subject?this.props.subject.hour*60*60+this.props.subject.minute*60:0,});
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        let hour = Math.floor(this.state.timeRun / (60 * 60));
        let minute= Math.floor((this.state.timeRun % (60 * 60)) / 60);
        this.onPause();
        if(this.props.subject){
            this.props.dispatch(startSubject(this.props.subject.id,{hour,minute}))
            console.log(this.props.subject.id)
        }
    }

    onStart=()=>{
        clearInterval(this.timer)
        this.timer = setInterval(()=>{
            let count=this.state.timeRun
            count--
            if(count<0){
                this.setState({onFinish:'well Done'})
                clearInterval(this.timer);
                return;
            }
                let hourleft = Math.floor(count / (60 * 60));
                let minuteleft = Math.floor((count % (60 * 60)) / 60);
                let secondleft = count % 60;

                this.setState({onFinish:`you have ${hourleft} hour ${minuteleft} minute and ${secondleft} second until reaching your goal`});
                this.setState({timeRun:count})
        },1000)
    }

    onPause=()=>{
        clearInterval(this.timer)
        let time = this.props.subject?this.props.subject.hour*60*60+this.props.subject.minute*60:0;
        if(this.state.timeRun<time){
            this.setState({buttonChange:'resume'})
            return;
        }
    }

    onReset=()=>{
        const resetConfirm=confirm('you have not finished, do you want to reset?')
        if(resetConfirm===true){
            clearInterval(this.timer)
            this.setState({timeRun:this.props.subject?this.props.subject.hour*60*60+this.props.subject.minute*60:0,
                            onFinish:'',
                            buttonChange:'start',
                            timer:null})

        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.subject?this.props.subject.subjectName:'there is nothing to do for now'}</p>
                <p>{this.props.subject?`you have ${this.props.subject.hour} hour and ${this.props.subject.minute} minute to work`:'there is no time set'}</p>
                <button onClick={this.onStart}>{this.state.buttonChange}</button>
                <button onClick={this.onPause}>pause</button>
                <button onClick={this.onReset}>reset</button>
                <p>{this.state.onFinish}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps=(state,props)=>{
    return{
        subject:state.subjects.find((subject)=>subject.id===props.match.params.id)
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BeginSubject)
```

Comment: Yeah doing so will make whatever make the state unchangable

Comment: when using props, you need to provide handlers to modify the props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use componentWillMount() life cycle method for this. set time run as 0 for intital value. componentWillMount() will calculate the time and set state. it will only be executed the first time component loads. else use componentWillRecieveProps();

**Disclaimer**: componentWillMount() **will only execute once** and any updates to the props wont be reflected in the child component.

```
  this.state={
        timeRun:0,
        onFinish:'',
        buttonChange:'start',
        timer:null
    }


componentWillMount(){
     this.setState({timeRun:this.props.subject?this.props.subject.hour*60*60+this.props.subject.minute*60:0,});
}
```

remember its always a bad practice to set props even in the way I suggested. The best way would be to **send the calculated value as props** to the child component. and use this.props.timeRun. this **prevents unwanted loops and updates**.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it when i am home

Comment: Thank you very much can you please take a look at my full component and give me your opinion about it? is there anything I should avoid in my code? thanks

Comment: looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to place it in a lifecycle method, componentWillReceiveProps(). There you can manage when you have to sync state with props and when you have not.